# How to use memcpy() c?

Tags: c, memcpy, string.h

I want to put `"12345"` instead of `"defgh"`

After the execution of the code written below, this is what i obtain : `original : abc12345`

but this is the output that i am looking for : `abc12345ijklmnop`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char original[20] = "abcdefghijklmnop";
  char src[6] = "12345";
  memcpy(original+3, src, sizeof(char) * 6);
  printf("original : %s\n", original);
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Don't copy the terminator from the 12345 string.

Comment: why copy the nul?

Answer (score 1):

You're copying over the terminating null byte in `src`.  You want to leave that out.

```
memcpy(original+3, src, sizeof(src) - 1);
```